# Коляска — один из лучших внедорожников, или — одна из лучших?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать?

1. Коляска Origamy — один из самых легких внедорожников.
2. Коляска Origamy — одна из самых легких внедорожников.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Коляска Origamy - один из самых легких внедорожников.

С подлежащим согласуется связка, а "один из самых легких внедорожников" - это **именная часть сказуемого**, выраженная словосочетанием.

Поэтому в именной части делается согласование количественно-местоименного слова "один" с существительным  в м.р.

Comment: Спасибо большое!